# Convert multi-dimensional array format in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have the following code below.

```
Group.all.collect {|group| [ group.name, group.id ]}.inspect
```

And this one outputs below.

```
[["Bankruptcy Group", 1], ["PIA Group", 2], ["Liquidation Group", 3]]
```

I want to convert to a different format like below.

```
{"Bankruptcy Group" => 1, "PIA Group"=> 2, "Liquidation Group"=> 3}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Are you using Ruby on Rails? There might be ActiveRecord methods that can be used to return model ids and names directly from the database using SQL.

Comment: Yes I do.  Hence for the original code at the beginning of the sentence.  I am still RoR newbie so I don't know a lot of ActiveRecord's API that I can fully muster it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create the hash directly:

```
Group.all.inject({}) { |h, g| h[g.name] = g.id; h }
```

Comment: Thanks xdazz. I like this one better.  Save me lines of code to write them out.  Thanks Heaps!

Answer (score 3):

```
[["Bankruptcy Group", 1], ["PIA Group", 2], ["Liquidation Group", 3]].to_h
```

Comment: I like this one.. simple and in one go.. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
array = Group.all.collect { |group| [ group.name, group.id ] }
hash = Hash[array]
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`to_h`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_h) method of [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html) can be used to convert enumerable objects to hashes when each item in the object can be interpreted as an array of the form `[key, value]`:

```
Group.all.map { |g| [g.name, g.id] }.to_h
```

From the documentation for `to_h`:

> Returns the result of interpreting `enum` as a list of `[key, value]` pairs.